# How to properly use custom user model in django, with custom templates instead of forms.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-custom-user

Can any one please tell me how to use Custom User model in django, so that user can register from front end. Or is there any way of creating new table for storing users and use the authentication of user model with that custom model.

```
# Custom User Model Code
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, favorite_color, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, favorite color
         and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            favorite_color=favorite_color,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, favorite_color, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            favorite_color=favorite_color,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['favorite_color']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin



# Templates Code as I want to use my own template instead of using forms.py
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            CustomUserModel
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="register">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Email : <input type="email" name="email"> <br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
            Favourite Colour : <input type="text" name='colour'><b>
            Bio : <textarea name='bio'></textarea>    <br>
            <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>



# Views Code
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        passwd = request.POST['password']
        clr = request.POST['colour']
        bio = request.POST['bio']
        user = MyUser(email=email,password=passwd,favorite_color=clr,bio=bio)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request,'home.html')
```

The main problem I am facing while registering a user from front end is that the password is saving into the data base in clear text-format, it is not getting hashed but while I am registering an user from the django admin panel the password is getting saved in proper hashed format. Why is it so ? What are the changes I need to perform in views.py to store the password in proper hash format in database?

I don't want to use django forms. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the name of your template is not home.html, so what you have to do is to change the last render like that :

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        passwd = request.POST['password']
        clr = request.POST['colour']
        bio = request.POST['bio']
        user = MyUser(email=email,password=passwd,favorite_color=clr,bio=bio)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request,'name_of_form_template')
```

Now if the method is post django will render the template with the form on it.

Comment: No the problem is with the password field as it is being saved in the clean text format not in hashed format. Why is it so? I want to store it in the database in hash format

Comment: Do you have set the right fields in your models.py ?